# Friends can't connect to my Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting, networking

My old computer broke so now I had to make a new Minecraft server, but now my friend Joe can't join.
The obvious "can't connect to server" shows up every time he tries it. I have forwarded the port and my firewall is turned off.

P.S. Whenever I test it with my IP as the IP instead of localhost, I can't connect either. I can connect fine when I use local host.

Comment: Guaranteed, you haven't port forwarded it properly.

Comment: Did you send them the public IP instead of the private IP

Comment: @Frank Have you considered actually explaining how he would go about doing that?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190718/mine-craft-properly-port-forwarded-but-cant-log-in?rq=1

Comment: I port forwarded 5 times. I was bound to get it right at least once

Comment: @DwarfSlice What kind of router does he have?WHat is the Ip of his PC/server in his local network? What port is the minecraft server running on? (probably the default 25565),... Explaining portforwarding requires more details. But it *is* a clear case of port forwarding issue.

Comment: @TheBrokenWalrus Doing it wrong 5 times won't help, and it's not because you do something five times that you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting a server, it is possible that you will need to go into your host settings and white-list your friend's username.
If you can connect fine using local host, this probably means that your public server is filtering who is allowed to join. I've heard that the newest Minecraft upgrade made server hosting more strict as far as public settings go.

Comment: As mentioned by the OP: he himself can't join if he uses his public Ip either, so it's not a whitelist issue.